# Weird Issue with File Server

Tags: networking, domain-name-system, share

I've got an odd issue I can't seem to resolve.

We have a file server on our domain. At random intervals certain users simply cannot access the shares that are set up, whilst other users can. We are all on the same domain.

The users who cannot access the shares cannot ping either the name of the server or the IP address (192.168.0.2).

A "fix" has been to assign a static IP to the user's who are having the issue. This resolved it for many, however that fix doesn't always seem to work.

We have a DNS server running as well. I am relatively inexperienced being a network admin, but here we are!

Any assistance to resolve this would be gratefully received, as it's beginning to give me sleepless nights.

Comment: Do you have any clients that never experience the problem? What's different between those clients and the others?

Comment: Hi Twisty, I cannot see any differences between those that experience the problem and those that don't. I have a static IP and I can't see it, others have it set dynamically and can't see it. Rebooting the DNS server and File Server resolved it for ONE person. All others still can't see it, ping it etc.

Comment: What is OS of clients/servers? Are either using 3rd party firewalls?

Comment: Server is Windows Server 2008 R2. OS on machines is Windows 7 64bit SP1. Firewall, we're using a NETGEAR ProSafe VPN Firewall FVS336GV2

Comment: Sorry, I was asking about the firewalls on the server & clients